# How come my css-grid is not set the way I intended?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want my Detail and bookmark button to be on the bottom right side of the grid. In my .popup-footer I set grid-column:3/4 (start from the third line and end at fourth line)and grid-row:2/3 (start from second line and end at third line)  right ? But I must have messed something up.

Please help me understand what I did wrong?
Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Heres the css

```
.popup-container {
  display: grid;
  grid: auto / 1fr 3fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
};

.marker-popup-img {
  height: 120px;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
};

.marker-popup-info {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
};

.popup-footer {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
};
```

Html

```
<div className="popup-container">
    <img className="marker-popup-img" src={getIcon(null ,`${r.grade_data.grade}`)} alt="A"></img>
    <address className  ="marker-popup-info">
      <h3><b>{r.dba}</b></h3><br/>
      <h4>{`Tel: ${r.phone}`}</h4>
      <p>{`${r.building} ${r.street}, ${r.boro} ${r.zipcode}`}</p>
    </address>
      <div className="popup-footer">
         <button onClick={()=>(setsRestaModal({
                                show: true,
                                data: {...r}
                              }))}
          >Details
         </button>
         <button>Bookmark</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Semicolons after the closing curly brackets is invalid CSS is prevent the css below it from being applied

Comment: Apart from the invalid `;` after each css block, `grid: auto / 1fr 3fr;` says you want 2 columns, so you shouldn't have a 4th line, 2 columns mean 3 lines. I'd suggest yo use named grid template areas so you don't need to mess with the lines and no shorthands if you are experimenting with the grid, then you can condense styles in the shorthand versions if you want.

Comment: You guys are correct, Thank you.